# Sorting files numerically in Perl

Tags: perl

I would like to sort files numerically using Perl script.

My files looks like below:

```
1:file1:filed2
3:filed1:field2
10:filed1:field2
4:field1:field2
7:field1:field2
```

I would like to display it as:

```
1:file1:filed2
3:filed1:field2
4:field1:field2
7:field1:field2
10:filed1:field2
```

Comment: Handily, `perl` has a `sort` function, which works quite nicely.

Comment: I am  writing to errr file: open($oErrorFileHandle, "> ".$InputFile.".error") || die "\n ERROR  -> failed to open $InputFile.error ..."; then  I trying to sort the error file as mentioned above by using the below program:#    foreach (sort <$oErrorFileHandle>)
#      {
#   print $oErrorFileHandle $_;
#      }
I am getting the error message as :readline() on closed filehandle Symbol::GEN3 at ./SCOM_importOnePosMigrationId line 226.
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question with additional detail. (like code snippets). They're hard to read in comments. (And comments get deleted a little more readily)

Answer (score 2):

The way `sort` works in perl, is that it works through your list, setting each element to `$a` and `$b` - then testing those. By default, it uses `cmp` which is an alphanumeric sort.

You've also got `<=>` which is a numeric sort, and the kind you're looking for. (Alpha sorts `10` ahead of `2` ).

So - all we need do is extract the numeric value of your key. There's a number of ways you could do this - the obvious being to take a subroutine that temporarily copies the variables:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

sub compare_first_num {
   my ( $a1 ) = split ( /:/, $a ); 
   my ( $b1 ) = split ( /:/, $b );
   return $a1 <=> $b1;
}

print sort compare_first_num <>;
```

This uses `<>` - the magic filehandle - to read `STDIN` or files specified on command line.

Or alternatively, in newer perls (5.16+):

```
print sort { $a =~ s/:.*//r <=> $b =~ s/:.*//r } <>;
```

We use the 'substitute-and-return' operation to compare just the substrings we're interested in. (Numerically).

Answer (score 1):

Split on `:` and store in a hash of arrays. Then you can sort and print out the hash keys:

```
my %data;

while(<DATA>){
    my @field = split(/:/);
    $data{$field[0]} = [@field[1..2]];
}

print join (':', $_, @{$data{$_}}) for sort { $a <=> $b } keys %data;

print "\n";
```

---

```
1:file1:filed2
3:filed1:field2
4:field1:field2
7:field1:field2
10:filed1:field2
```

Comment: Thanks.But I am writing my script output to error file.And I want to display my error in order.First field above represent the line number.I am writing to the error file and closing the file.When I am trying to read it again to sort I am getting message readline() on closed filehandle Symbol::GEN3 at ./SCOM_importOnePosMigrationId .My close command $oErrorFileHandle->close();

Answer (score 1):

For simple and fast solution, use [Sort::Key::Natural](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sort::Key::Natural) (fast natural sorting) module:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Sort::Key::Natural qw( natsort );

open my $fh, "<", "file.txt" or die $!;
my @files = natsort <$fh>;
close $fh;
print @files;
```

Output:

```
1:file1:filed2
3:filed1:field2
4:field1:field2
7:field1:field2
10:filed1:field2
```